# How to test database save and delete methods?

Tags: apex

I cannot add a throw exception to the list committed to the database so how do I add an error to the list to successfully test negative save / delete?

```
Database.DeleteResult[] drList = Database.delete(list1, True); //this is all or none



    // again create counter
    Integer i=0;
    // Iterate through each returned result
    for(Database.DeleteResult dr : drList) {
        if (!dr.isSuccess()) { // this is where I need to add error but is read only list?
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the object that is represented by `list1`?

Comment: yes but its a list on a related object that is being updated. I have tried to modify the list, I think I am just not doing so correctly for a delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do when testing delete errors like this is:

1. Setup test data
2. Get the data in the list I am trying to delete
3. Delete the record in my test method
4. Call the method I am testing (that does the delete)

This will throw an already deleted error.

How you do it depends on how your code is set up. It may require you properly refactor some of your code to isolate the creation of the list and then the delete etc.

For inserts and updates I try to find something that will cause an error as well. For updates, I delete the record first or populate with data that does not meet required field values. Same for inserts sans the delete. If I cannot find anything for inserts sometimes I delete the parent if it is  MD so when it tries to insert it throws an error.

Again, all this depends on your org, env, and code structure on the exact **how** of it

Comment: This is good Ill try this.

Comment: I have it set up to database.delete then the part I am trying to test on is the loop thru the (!isSuccess())

Comment: I think this would work if its on the same list. Im doing a query on a related list for trigger.new/ trigger.old so I think in this case it won't work. Not sure. Good solution though.

Comment: @AndrewMayes - There i always a way to get it to work.May involve modifying your code i a good way to be more adherent to separation of Concern. But there is always (99%) a way to delete the record after putting it in the list. I am sure you will find it.

Comment: Is it acceptable to wrap this database in a try catch with all or none true?

Comment: @AndrewMayes IMHO No. it would also not help you get around the proper assertion as you would still have to generate an error. Along with several other reasons

Comment: Kind of felt the same way looking at the documentation. Thanks @eric

Answer (score 1):

> how do I add an error to the list to successfully test negative save / delete?

One way you can simulate an error during a delete operation is by artificially creating an error condition in your production code that you control from within your test. You can do this by using a static variable in a trigger handler class which you can use create an artificial error or exception to be thrown any time you so choose.

Here is a fully self-contained example

The trigger:

```
trigger ErrorTestTrigger on Account (before delete) {
    ErrorTestHelper.doWork();
}
```

The helper:

```
public class ErrorTestHelper {
    public static boolean CreateArtificialError = false;

    public static void doWork() {
        if (CreateArtificialError == true) {
            for (Account acct : (List<Account>)Trigger.old) {
                acct.addError('Artificially generated error');                    
            }

            // alternatively you could throw an Exception here
            // instead of adding an error to the records in the trigger
            // throw new YourCustomException('Artificially created exception'); 
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
@isTest
private class ErrorTestUnitTest {

    static testMethod void testDeleteError() {
        List<Account> aList = new List<Account>();
        aList.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAccount'));
        insert aList;

        Test.startTest();
        ErrorTestHelper.CreateArtificialError = true;

        // this is going to throw a System.DmlException
        // if you want to process results, allOrNone must be false
        Database.DeleteResult[] results = database.delete(aList, true);

        for (Database.DeleteResult result : results) {
            system.debug(result.isSuccess());
            system.debug(result.getErrors());
        }

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

The results

**All or None: true** throws `System.DMLException`

> 12:54:19:052 EXCEPTION_THROWN [14]|System.DmlException: Delete failed.
>   First exception on row 0 with id 0016A000002baUMQAY; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Artificially generated error: []

**All or None: false** returns `List<Database.DeleteResult>` which can be iterated

> 12:51:42:061 USER_DEBUG
>   [18]|DEBUG|(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=Artificially
>   generated error;getStatusCode=FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION;])

Comment: Yeah but addError() doesn't prevent them from being deleted right? I think this only applies to DML calls and not database.

Comment: it will prevent any database transaction from being successful regardless of how you initiated the operation (`delete yourList;` or `database.delete(yourList, allOrNone);`)

Comment: yeah have you actually done this before?

Comment: 14:23:14:102 USER_DEBUG [147]|DEBUG|Save Result: Database.SaveResult[getErrors=();getId=02c0n0000039CrdAAE;isSuccess=true;]

Comment: Documentation literally says 'any DML' https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Comment: @AndrewMayes I've updated this answer with a fully functional example. Additionally, database operation and DML operation and DML call are synonymous. `.addError()` prevents a record from being committed during the database transaction.

Comment: _"yeah have you actually done this before?"_ - Yes I have, which is why I provided the answer. You should work on being less condescending when you're asking for assistance.

Comment: For one thing, your database.delete is in a test class. before i respond, can you please explain to me if this would work in the helper class?

Comment: Im not trying to test for an addError method by running database delete in my test. Im trying to test my database delete for when it fails

Comment: You are trying to test a failing delete operation. The above is an example of a test which artificially creates a failing delete operation by leveraging a static variable in conjunction with a trigger handler class. (This pattern cannot be used if the logic is contained directly in the trigger.) If you would like help adapting this pattern to your own code, I'll need to see more of your code in your question's body.

Comment: Ok I guess my only question is do I need to do something else special to get the addError to cause an exception besides adding it to the object like you have here?

Comment: Ok i see where the issue is. I am doing an operation on a related list I'm getting from a query in my helper class and it is an after delete on the object doing DML. Thats why I was trying to specify that I needed it on the list. My helper does the database call on the related list itself.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I did that actually worked. Used the static variable as Mark suggested with test.isRunningTest() and then modified a text field to show an error in the !isSuccess loop: `AccessLevel = 'INVALIDNAME'`